# How to prepare statement in Postgresql when using crosstab

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine, prepared-statement

Using Symfony (2.8) and Doctrine, with Postgresql (9.5). I need to use `crosstab` to pivot my results using prepared statements in PHP.

My schema is different and complicated so, for the sake of simplicity, let's take an example table straight from Postgresql's [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html):

```
CREATE TABLES sales(year int, month int, qty int);
INSERT INTO sales VALUES(2007, 1, 1000);
INSERT INTO sales VALUES(2007, 2, 1500);
INSERT INTO sales VALUES(2007, 7, 500);
INSERT INTO sales VALUES(2007, 11, 1500);
INSERT INTO sales VALUES(2007, 12, 2000);
INSERT INTO sales VALUES(2008, 1, 1000);
```

Now, here is the PHP code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from CROSSTAB(
    'SELECT year, month, qty FROM sales WHERE year = :year',
    'SELECT m FROM generate_series(1,12) m'
  ) as (
    year int,
    \"Jan\" int,
    \"Feb\" int,
    \"Mar\" int,
    \"Apr\" int,
    \"May\" int,
    \"Jun\" int,
    \"Jul\" int,
    \"Aug\" int,
    \"Sep\" int,
    \"Oct\" int,
    \"Nov\" int,
    \"Dec\" int
  );";

    $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $params = ['year' => 2008];

    $statement->execute($params);
```

Executing this will throw an error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: :year
```

I think this may be because `:year` is being considered as part of a string literal and thus, it's unable to bind it. How do I make this work? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

You're right. Quoted placeholders are not placeholders. They're just part of a string and only LOOK like placeholders. Build the string literal in pieces, instead:

```
$sql = "select * from crosstab(
    'select year, month, qty from sales order by 1 where year = ' + :year,
                                                                ^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Addendum: since I'm working in Postgresql, concatenation requires two pipe symbols ||, thus: `$sql = "... crosstab('select ... where year = ' || :year,` .

Comment: Further addendum: if the named parameter is going to be a string value, the single quotes would need to be escaped. Since this is part of PHP code, three single quotes will do that: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM CROSSTAB('... WHERE email = ''' || :email || ''' ORDER BY ...', ......)`